# std::vector<double> shrink to fit?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to shrink the size of a vector that I have, but i get an error when i use the `myvector.shrink_to_fit();`
and it tells me:

> error: no member named
>         '`shrink_to_fit' in 'std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >'`

and myvector is defined in the header as:

```
std::vector<double> myvector;
```

what does this error mean?

Comment: Compile with C++11.

Answer (score 4):

[`shrink_to_fit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) is a new C++11 feature that won't be in every compiler yet.

The old way of doing this was to swap with a temporary:

```
std::vector<double>(myvector).swap(myvector);
```

Comment: @Gracita, check the edit, I had left out something very important.